# Automatic creation of caching directories

Tags: tikz-pgf, external-files, directory, write-file, portability

The following MWE writes a cache file to the `tikzcache` directory

```
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{external}
  \tikzexternalize
  \tikzsetexternalprefix{tikzcache/}
\begin{document}
  \tikzsetnextfilename{myfig}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (1,1) {test};
  \node at (2,2) {test2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It seems I  need to compile it with:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape ...
```

First of all, why `-shell-escape` is required?
Based on my knowledge, `-shell-escape`  enables the TeX primitive `\write18{command}` construct. This construct writes to the special stream 18, which is not an actual file, but  a way of sending commands to the system shell. However, creating the cached file should be possible with the non-privileged TeX primitive `write`.  Besides security, since one typically builds PDFs with some LaTeX editor, that requires `-shell-escape` to be set in the editor build commands, which makes the LaTeX file non-portable.

Also, to reduce clutter,

```
\tikzsetexternalprefix{tikzcache/}
```

sets to write TikZ cached files in the `tikzcache` directory.
My problem is that this directory should already exist. I could create it automatically in LaTeX with an `\immediate\write18{...}` command. However, besides requiring a `-shell-escape`, the command would be far from simple.
In fact,  to avoid the a failure, one should add the logic to skip file  creation after the first build, that is when the directory already exist. In Linux that could be as simple simple as that:

```
\immediate\write18{mkdir -p tikzcache}
```

However, that would not work under different systems (Windows), again making the `.tex` file non-portable.